# How can we create Dockerfile for Angular with dotnet core api project?

Tags: docker, devops

I have created the Dockerfile using visual studio for my dotnet api project but how can we integrate the client app in the docker file. I have created the docker file which looks like:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Locomote-e-Client.Service/Locomote-e-Client.Service.csproj", "Locomote-e-Client.Service/"]
COPY ["Locomote-e-Client.Core/Locomote-e-Client.Core.csproj", "Locomote-e-Client.Core/"]
COPY ["Locomote-e-Client.Common/Locomote-e-Client.Common.csproj", "Locomote-e-Client.Common/"]
COPY ["Locomote-e-Client.Data/Locomote-e-Client.Data.csproj", "Locomote-e-Client.Data/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Locomote-e-Client.Service/Locomote-e-Client.Service.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Locomote-e-Client.Service"
RUN dotnet build "Locomote-e-Client.Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Locomote-e-Client.Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM node:10.21 as nodebuilder
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY Locomote-e-ClientApp/package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install
COPY Locomote-e-ClientApp/. /usr/src/app
RUN npm run build

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
RUN mkdir -p /app/ClientApp/dist
COPY --from=nodebuilder /usr/src/app/dist/. /app/ClientApp/dist/
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Locomote-e-Client.Service.dll"]
```

Whenever I have created the image by using this docker file then it will create the image successfully. But when I tried to run that image using container then it is not running in container.

Command to build the image

```
docker build -t ashishrajput194/locomate:v1 .
```

Command to run as container

```
docker run -p 80:80 -d ashishrajput194/locomate:v1
```

It is not showing any error but the container exits automatically. I am not able to run the application.